# Matrix multiplication program

Tags: c

The code below shows segmentation error.
The error prevails
Tried many changes but of no use

```
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
  static int a[100][100],b[100][100],c[100][100]={0};
  int m,n,p,i,j,k;
  printf("Enter no pf rows and colums for matrix A");
  scanf("%d%d",&m,&n);
  for(i=0;i<=m-1;i++)
  {
    for(j=0;j<=n-1;j++)
    {
      printf("enter no.");
      scanf("%d",&a[i][j]);
    }
  }
  printf("Enter no. of column for matrix b");
  scanf("%d",&p);
  for(i=0;i<=n-1;i++)
  {
    for(j=0;j<=p-1;j++)
    {
      printf("enter no.");
      scanf("%d",&b[i][j]);
    }
  }
  for(i=0;i<=m-1;i++)
  {
    for(j=0;i<=p-1;j++)
    {
      c[i][j]=0;
      for(k=0;k<=n-1;k++)
      {
        c[i][j]=c[i][j]+a[i][k]*b[k][j];
      }
    }
  }
  printf(" The resultant matrix is");
  for(i=0;i<=m-1;i++)
  {
    for(j=0;j<=p-1;j++)
    {
      printf("%d\t",c[i][j]);
    }
  printf("\n");
  }

getch();
}
```

Tried it on turbo c++

Error 139
Segmentation error

Comment: "Tried many changes", show them, explain them. In which way did they fail? Exactly the same way? (Downvote not by me.)

Comment: It is probably time to do some systematic debugging. Try the recommendations here   https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Scanf() has a return value for a reason, ignore it at your own risk.

Comment: Please learn about and apply indentation, it often turns out to be a very helpful debugging tool, especially when in the context of structure and control flow mistakes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Error 139 Segmentation error

this is because

> ```
>      for(j=0;i<=p-1;j++)
> ```

must be

```
    for(j=0;j<=p-1;j++)
```

currently *j* is increased without end so `c[i][j]=0;` and other accesses are out of the array with an undefined behavior (your segmentation fault)

---

Other remarks :

- to do `for(j=0; j < p; j++)` is a better choice compatible with for instance `size_t` with is the right type for an index
- I strongly encourage you to check if your *scanf* success, currently you do not know if valid numbers was enter, for instance

  ```
  if (scanf("%d%d",&m,&n)!= 2)
    fprintf(stderr, "invalid numbers");
  else {
  ```
- also check when necessary the enter values are > 0, this must be the case for the number of rows and columns

Comment: Also, `j<=p-1;` is easier to read and less prone to error as `j<p;`. When `p` is `unsigned`, the loop test can fail.

Comment: @WeatherVane I do not get it. Please elaborate, maybe using an example.

Comment: `p` is a variable. When `p == 0` the limit `p - 1` will not do what is required, if `unsigned`. It's also harder for the brain and more work for the computer. In the case of a literal value, say there are `10` elements, if you write `j <= 9` that introduces another literal, which should really be the same `j < 10` that was already used.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your support you're absolutely right